# php - how to return html inside json

Tags: php, json

I have some html inside my json array .this is an example :

```
    {
    "contacts": [
{ "id" : "1215"  ,"price2":"0","tozih":"<span class="im_message_author_wrap" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; text-align: start;"><br><span class="copyonly" style="color: transparent; display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline; width: 1px; height: 0px; background: none 0px center no-repeat; font-size: 0px; float: left; text-rendering: auto; user-select: none;">:</span></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;"></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;"></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;"></span><span style="white-space: pre-wrap; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;">عكس تزيين شده زنجيرهاي استيل</span>     تست <br>"} ]
```

the problem is , the double quote " is making json invalid ,is there any way to convert or encode ? 
could you help me with this ?

Comment: https://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/ this post give you brief detail hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Try given script**

```
 {
    "contacts": [
                  { "id" : "1215"  ,"price2":"0","tozih":'<span class="im_message_author_wrap" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; text-align: start;"><br><span class="copyonly" style="color: transparent; display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline; width: 1px; height: 0px; background: none 0px center no-repeat; font-size: 0px; float: left; text-rendering: auto; user-select: none;">:</span></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;"></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;"></span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;"></span><span style="white-space: pre-wrap; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size: 13px; text-align: start;">عكس تزيين شده زنجيرهاي استيل</span>     تست <br>'} 
                ]
 }
```